# User not authorized for deployment when "runCommand" in "postSync" with run dotnet dll

Tags: iis, deployment, web-deployment, iis-8, runcommand

I have IIS user and run under on him `-postSync:runCommand`. 
The command includes call for `dotnet.exe` and dll app with the migrations to db. `

I've created Rule (runCommand) in `IIS/Management Service Delegation`. For that I appointed a user from the admin group and set path `"C:\Windows\System32"` for cm. I tried different options: `{userScope}`, the dotnet and dll path but it didn't help me.

I tried call simple cmd and appcmd command and it works.

Comment: Hi! Have you checked this link?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/troubleshooting-web-deploy/troubleshooting-common-problems-with-web-deploy

Comment: Thanks. But how the "common problems" will able to help me? As I wrote above, the post commands runed and all necessary one installed. Most likely the problem is in setting the rules.